# Short story - glass man assassinated?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

Does anyone know the title or author of a short story that was published in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction magazine, 1981 (not sure of month), where a man is turned into glass/mirror and is assassinated in the end?

Comment: There is a [listing of the stories in the 1981 Asimov magazine here](http://www.unz.org/Pub/AsimovsSF?View=YearContents&Period=1981). You could have a look through and see if any of the titles look familiar.

Comment: Thanks, John. I'll see if anything rings a bell.

Comment: You may need to rethink either the date range or the source; I've recently re-read IASFM from 1977 through 1983, and I didn't come across any matching story.  The closest I found was "Blue Heart" in the Nov. 1982 issue where a man (and later a woman) is made into a cyborg to extend their lives, and the transparent skin is described as glass.  But there's no assassination.

Comment: TY, DavidW!
I only had an IASFM subscription for about 6 months, I was in about 7th grade. I read the story and still remember it today. I'm an English teacher now and would love to include it in my classroom. I'll describe what I remember to the best of my ability from so long ago. I can't remember how the story opens, but I do remember the climax. The main character, after transforming into "glass" served to "reflect" people's ideas and attitudes, prejudices and whatnot. He is giving a speech at a rally promoting equality (?) when he is shot by a sniper. ...helps?